# ASP.NET Core Delete Cookies after JWT expire

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt, httpcookie

I store my JWT in HTTPOnly Cookies, and after the token expire, the cookie still active. How can I delete or expire the cookie, when the JTW expires too?

Here is my Startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();
            options.Events.OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {

                if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("X-Access-Token"))
                {
                    context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["X-Access-Token"];
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        })
           .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
               options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
               options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

           });
```

At Login, I pass my JWT to the cookie:

```
Response.Cookies.Append("X-Access-Token", generatedToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict, Secure = true });
```

Comment: After your token expires, have you tried something like `SlidingExpiration = true; Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);` ? You could have a try and let us know if it works.